# C++ namespace not declared but it is?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I'm having a compile time problem. New to C++ so I'm sure it's simple. I am gettign the current error.

```
diarydb.cpp: In function ‘bool editdate(int, mysqlpp::Connection&)’: diarydb.cpp:413:
error: ‘format_tests’ has not been declared
```

but diardby.cpp I have declared format_tests here

```
namespace format_tests {
  bool testdateformat(string &date);
  bool tesettimeformat(string &time);
  bool lengthcheck(string &in,int length);

}
```

with

```
bool format_tests::testdateformat(string &date){
  // tests format of dat input for MYSQL form at of YYYY-MM-DD
  // Need to tweak regex to restrict 0 < MM < 12 and 0 < DD <31.

  const boost::regex e("\\d{4}\\x2D\\d{2}\\x2D\\d{2}");
  return boost::regex_match(date,e);
}
```

the compiler compler of the call here.

```
  bool dbsetget::editdate(int e_id,mysqlpp::Connection &con){

        char evdate[11];

    cout << "Input start time" << endl;
    cin.getline(evdate,11,'\n'); // restrict legth of input with getline.lenght of input

    string date = evdate;

    if (format_tests::testdateformat(date)){
    mysqlpp::Query query = con.query();
    query <<"UPDATE main SET date="<< quote_only << date <<"WHERE d_Id ="<< e_id;

    return query.exec();
    }
    else
    {
      cerr << "Date not in correct format. YYYY-MM-DD ";
      return false;
    };
  }
```

I don't understand what the problem is? I have declared format_tests namespace Can anyone please guide me?

I'm sure there are plenty of to mistakes in here too but this one has got me pretty confused.

Comment: Is the format_tests namespace declared earlier in the file than its use?

Comment: There is not enough information here to pinpoint the problem, so we have to guess. Maybe namespace format_tests is not visible at the spot where the error occurs?

Comment: all this code is in one cpp file?

Comment: Is the first block of code earlier in the source file than the third? If it's later, then that's the problem; functions and namespaces must be declared before you can use them. Also, is `namespace format_tests` in the global namespace, or do you have another namespace surrounding that?

Comment: It's all in the same file but the namespace is declared after the editdate() functions. I think Mike and Erik have the answer. Perfect thanks. Dunce hat now on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like the file in which you have

```
format_tests::testdateformat(date)
```

cannot see the

```
namespace format_tests
{
     bool testdateformat(string &date);
};
```

Have you included the header file where the testdateformat is declaired?

Comment: Perfect. I knew it was going to be something stupid. namespace declaration was after functions call in cpp file. Thanks all.

Comment: This may look straightforward, but in a big project I have two `.hh` files with the same name (in different folders) and due to an issue in the makefile I was pointing to the wrong one and getting this error. Quite confusing, but your answer helped me to find the problem!